# google apps script - gmail - return message (not thread) via filter

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I have specific incoming emails assigned different labels and I have threading (conversation view) disabled in settings.
I can enter a search in the web app that returns the specific messages I want,

eg:
"label: customer01 label:report"

However using the exact same filter with the API returns the thread and all messages there-in that Google has decided are part of the same conversation (even though in the real world they are not) which means my script processes messages it should not in addition to those it should.

eg:
var threads = GmailApp.search(gSearchExp); // where gSearchExp is the aforementioned filter

Is there a way I can search for and return messages, NOT threads?

Answer (score 4):

How about using Gmail API? I think that by using Gmail API, you can retrieve the message with the specific labels. The sample script is as follows.

**In order to use this, please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google Services and API console. You can see how to do it at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50883782).**

#### Sample script:

```
var userId = "me";
var query = "label:customer01 label:report";
var res = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId, {q: query});
var ids = res.messages.map(function(e){return e.id});
Logger.log(ids) // Message IDs with the specific labels.
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the message IDs with the specific labels are retrieved. For example, if you want to retrieve the message bodies, please retrieve them using the retrieved message IDs.
- Please modify `var userId = "me"` to your environment.

#### Reference:

- [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: I don't think this works, he's asking specifically for Google Apps Script. You're using the Gmail API for general Javascript, which is different.

Comment: @Cornelius Roemer Thank you for your comment. From your comment, I could notice that `：` of `label：customer01 label：report` was 2 bytes character. I modified it. Thank you so much. By the way, this is Google Apps Script. How about this?

Comment: You're right, it does work in Apps Script. Genius! It's not mentioned in the documentation of Apps script at all. You're basically hacking the Apps Script with undocumented features from the Gmail API, right? Or how could you know that this syntax would work?
Also, you need to add pageToken to make it work with many results. This worked for me: ```var nextPageToken="11930073761860123345";  var res = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId, {q: query,pageToken: nextPageToken});```

Comment: I found it! It's the "Advanced Gmail Service" as opposed to "built-in": https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail
Thanks a lot still for opening my eyes to this - Google's documentation is sometimes very terse for the beginner.

Comment: @Cornelius Roemer Thank you for replying. There are several methods that built-in methods of Google Apps script cannot be achieved and only Advanced Google services can be achieved. In this case, Advanced Google services is used. And also, when Advanced Google services is used, the process cost can be also reduced. For example, [Ref1](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/030203c695b308606041587e6da269e7) and [Ref2](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)