# Filtering for emails not coming from a given domain with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

In Google Apps Script I am executing the following script:

```
var  filter = "in:inbox from:-domain.com",
    threads = GmailApp.search(filter);

Logger.log(threads.length);
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
  for (var j = 0; j < msgs.length; j++) {
    Logger.log('Thread ' + i + ', Mess. ' + j + ' ' + msgs[j].getFrom() + ' ' + msgs[j].getSubject());
  } 
}
```

The objective is to list all the messages in the inbox which are **not** sent from an address under a certain `domain.com`.
The docs say that,  in `GmailApp.search(query)`, `query` "is the search query, as you would type it into Gmail". However, the results that I get from the code are different from the conversations that I get copying and pasting `in:inbox from:-domain.com` in the Gmail search box.

Specifically, via the API, I get an extra  thread. This thread consists of two messages, where the initial message is from "foo@department.domain.com" and the answer "bar@domain.com". Given `filter`, both of them should not be there, as from Gmail app results.
Why it is not so?

### EDIT

After some days of testing, I saw a correlation between the problem mentioned here and snoozed messages. This hint should help  to reproduce the issue. For better understanding and analysis, I am opening posting a  question  specifically focus on this.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. Can you give detailed steps to reproduce it, starting from the creation of the problematic email and answer?

Comment: @Aerials: I am trying to reproduce, but the problem affects only one message, which I cannot yet reproduce. The `from` field, returned by `getFrom()`, is like `NAME SURNAME <name.surname@subdomain.domain.com>`. So it should be filtered out by `in:inbox from:-domain.com`. In fact, there are other inbox messages from the same user which are correctly not logged. The difference could be that the message wrongly logged is a forwarded message. Could this confuse the API?

Comment: See if this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183973/google-apps-script-gmail-return-message-not-thread-via-filter

Comment: @Aerials: Using the Advanced Google Services, the filter seems to work. I can only tell this by exploring the variables using the editor debug service. In fact, I can't find in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages) an equivalent of `getFrom()`,  `getSubject()`, etc., as in standard `GmailApp` interface, and there are no JavaScript examples. Any link?

Answer (score 0):

The message headers (From, Subject, etc) can be retrieved using the Gmail API, (In Apps Script it's the Gmail Advanced Service) you can do a request, specifying the metadataHeaders parameters that you want to retrieve. Like the following [Example request](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22%3CMESSAGE-ID-HERE%3E%22%2C%22format%22%3A%22metadata%22%2C%22metadataHeaders%22%3A%5B%22From%22%2C%22Subject%22%5D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22payload(headers)%22%7D)

Comment: Please, see the edit, where I found the crux of the matter.