# Forward email message with MailApp instead of GmailApp

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Forward emails with MailApp instead of GmailApp to preserve emojis.

We have a filter to tag emails we want to forward.
And then a google-apps-script to parse those emails and forward them.
Encountered a problem where using GmailApp.forward having a problem with some emojis. [(ref. my previous question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018152/forwarded-emails-via-script-missing-emoticons?noredirect=1#comment98682413_56018152)

The solution was to send the email with MailApp instead of GmailApp.
But MailApp does not have a forward function [like GmailApp's GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forward(String)) :(

So how do I fix this code?

```
var label = 'WisWebRelay';
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads();

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
  for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {  
    var email = messages[j];
    email.forward('my@email.com');
  }
}
```

Will I have to get html-message, all inline images and attachment from my mail object, and build a message and send with [MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailto-replyto-subject-body)?

Comment: According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686254/is-there-any-way-to-insert-emojis-into-google-apps-script) to your previous question, you could also use the Gmail API. Is there a particular reason you're limiting yourself to MailApp?

Comment: Bahhh, did not read past first solution :( 
Will follow the Gmail API route.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to insert emojis into Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686254/is-there-any-way-to-insert-emojis-into-google-apps-script)