# Gmail shows emoji in the Inbox but not when email is opened

Tags: html, google-apps-script, gmail, emoji

I'm creating emails with Google Apps Script and I tried to include an emoji

😅

so for testing I just put this inside the html template:

```
<p>&#x1F605</p>
```

When I receive the email, I can see it in the Inbox but when I open the message I just see this `&#x1F605`.

What should I do to correctly display them?

Comment: @Cooper oh... thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50883782/1675954