# Extract a list of unique text characters/ emojis from a cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, unique, google-sheets-formula

I have a text in cell (A1) like this:
✌☝️

I want to extract the unique emojis from this cell into separate cells:
✌☝️

Is this possible?

Comment: Google Appscript could be your solution. Refer this question in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847697/insert-emoji-unicode-from-google-sheets-to-an-email-using-script-editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to put each character of `✌☝️` to each cell by splitting using the built-in function of Google Spreadsheet.

#### Sample formula:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.)","$1@"),"@")
```

- `✌☝️` is put in a cell "A1".
- Using `REGEXREPLACE`, `@` is put to between each character like `✌@@@@☝@️@@@@@@`.
- Using `SPLIT`, the value is splitted with `@`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- In your question, the value of `️` which cannot be displayed is included. It's `\ufe0f`. So "G1" can be seen like no value. But the value is existing. So please be careful this. If you want to remove the value, you can use `✌☝`.

#### References:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

### Added:

From [marikamitsos's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963877/extract-a-list-of-unique-text-characters-emojis-from-a-cell/60964499?noredirect=1#comment107858745_60964499), I could notice that my understanding was not correct. So the final result is as follows. This is from [marikamitsos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527780/marikamitsos).

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.)","$1@"),"@"))))
```

Comment: I believe that since the question is about how to _"extract the **unique** emojis"_ the formula could be `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.)","$1@"),"@"))))`

Comment: @marikamitsos Oh! Thank you for your comment. I couldn't understand about the meaning of "unique". So I couldn't notice that OP wants to retrieve the values by removed the duplicated characters. This is rue to my poor English skill. Thank you for your support. From your comment, I could confirm that my answer was not correct for achieving OP's goal. So I have to delete my answer. So can you post it as an answer? By this, your answer can achieve OP's goal.

Comment: Thank you @marikamitsos! That's exactly what I wanted. I wanted to extract each unique emoji and then split them out into individual cells. Thanks @Tanaike for your help as well!

Comment: _"So I have to delete my answer."_. Please don't. You did all the hard work. I merely pointed out the "unique" request. :)

Comment: @marikamitsos Thank you for replying and your support. From your replying, I would like to leave my answer. Also I added the final result you proposed in my answer. Could you please confirm it. Thank you so much, again.

Comment: _"Thank you so much"_. **Thank you**. Your contribution here is invaluable. As a request, please have a look from time to time to [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) as well. You would be great help to all the users there.

Answer (score 0):

or try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, REPT("(.)", LEN(A1))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: @JvdV I think that in this formula, it is required to be `LEN(A1) / 2` like `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, REPT("(.)", LEN(A1) / 2)))))`. Because each emoji character in OP's question is 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

Appears, one of the best formula solutions would be:

`=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.)","$1@"),"@")`

You may also add some additional checks like skin tones & intermediate chars:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(.["&CHAR(8205)&CHAR(65039)&"]*)","@$1"),"@"))`

It will help to join some emojis as a single emoji.

## Script

More precise way is to use the script:

https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter/blob/master/index.js

↑

1. Add the code to Script editor
2. Add code for sample usage:

```
function splitEmojis(string) {
  var splitter = new GraphemeSplitter();
  // split the string to an array of grapheme clusters (one string each)
  var graphemes = splitter.splitGraphemes(string);
  return graphemes;
}
```

[Tests](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iO7YjYWyfseQu_YCfRbGDPg7NskOgMu_iO1iGjr7KxY/edit#gid=386718376)

## Not 100% precise

### 1

Please note: some emojis are not correctly shown in sheets

[image]

↑ emojis:

- flag: England
- flag: Scotland
- flag: Wales
- black flag

are the same for Google Sheets.

### 2

Vlookup function in #GoogleSheets and in #Excel thinks chars

- #️⃣ and
- *️⃣

are the same!