# How to use Emoji in email subject using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, emoji

I am trying to send out an email using Google Apps Script.

```js
// try 1
const subject = 'Hello World ';

// try 2
const subject = 'Hello World ' + String.fromCodePoint('0x1F600');

GmailApp.sendEmail(
  'abc@gmail.com', subject, '',
  {htmlBody: '<p>Hello World </p>', name: 'ABC'}
);
```

When I use a ⭐, it works perfectly in both subject and HTML body. However, when I use , it shows black diamonds with question marks in both subject and HTML body.

I have also checked [How to insert an emoji into an email sent with GmailApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686254/how-to-insert-an-emoji-into-an-email-sent-with-gmailapp) but it only showcases how to use it in the body of the email, not the subject.

I have tried using MailApp and it worked but I don't want to use it for
some reasons.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: From your updated question, I understood that you wanted to know the method for achieving your goal using `GmailApp.sendEmail` without using `MailApp.sendEmail`. By this, I reopened your question.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, any idea on how to achieve the goal?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The emoji in the body displays successfully.`, can I ask you about the method for achieving it? Because when I tested your script, the emoji in the email body cannot be correctly shown. I apologize for this.

Comment: Try to see it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50690214/5640200

Comment: For example, when the HTML body doesn't include the emoji and you want to include the emoji in only the subject using `GmailApp.sendEmail`, I think that this can be achieved. How about this?

Comment: @MichelePisani Hi. I tried your suggestion. When I use ⭐, it works. But when I use  it doesn't. I have also tried something like this `const subject = 'Hello World  ';` by adding extra space after smile emoji, but still getting question marks.

Comment: HI @Tanaike, I have updated my question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that when `GmailApp.sendEmail` is used, the subject of `Hello World ` can be used using a workaround. But in this case, `Hello World ` cannot be used for the HTML body. On the other hand, when `MailApp.sendEmail` is used, both the subject and HTML body including the emoji can be used. But from your question, it seems that you don't want to use `MailApp.sendEmail`. So, as other direction, in your goal, can you use Gmail API?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, Gmail API will work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script using Gmail API as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike. I haven't got time to implement your solution. I will be working on it in a couple of days. I will let you know for sure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understood your situation. I would like to wait for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to send an gmail including the emoji like `・` in the subject using Google Apps Script.
- You wanted to know the method for achieving your goal using `GmailApp.sendEmail` without using `MailApp.sendEmail`.
- But, when `GmailApp.sendEmail` is used, the subject can include the emoji. But the emoji cannot be used in the email body. So I proposed to use Gmail API in this situation. For my question of `as other direction, in your goal, can you use Gmail API?`, you answered `Yes, Gmail API will work.`. So I understood that your goal can be achieved using Gmail API.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, Gmail API is used with Advanced Google services.
- And, when you want to include the emoji like `・` in the email subject, the subject is sent as the base64 data.

  - When the value include the emoji is converted to the base64 data, in my test, it seems that the value is required to be converted to the base64 as UFT-8.
  - I confirmed that this workaround can be also used for `GmailApp.sendEmail`.

When above points are reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set the variables in the function `main()` and run the function `main()`.

```
function convert(toEmail, fromEmail, name, subject, textBody, htmlBody) {
  const boundary = "boundaryboundary";
  const mailData = [
    `MIME-Version: 1.0`,
    `To: ${toEmail}`,
    `From: "${name}" <${fromEmail}>`,
    `Subject: =?UTF-8?B?${Utilities.base64Encode(subject, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)}?=`,
    `Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=${boundary}`,
    ``,
    `--${boundary}`,
    `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`,
    ``,
    textBody,
    ``,
    `--${boundary}`,
    `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`,
    `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`,
    ``,
    Utilities.base64Encode(htmlBody, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8),
    ``,
    `--${boundary}--`,
  ].join("\r\n");
  return Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(mailData);
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const toEmail = "###"; // Please set the email for `to`.
  const fromEmail = "###"; // Please set the email for `from`.
  const name = "ABC";
  const subject = "Hello World ・";
  const textBody = "sample text body ・";
  const htmlBody = "<p>Hello World ・</p>";
  var raw = convert(toEmail, fromEmail, name, subject, textBody, htmlBody);
  Gmail.Users.Messages.send({raw: raw}, "me");
}
```

#### Note:

- When you want to use the emoji with the subject using `GmailApp.sendEmail`, you can also use the following script. But, in this case, in my environment, when the emoji is included in the text body and HTML body, the emoji cannot be seen. So please be careful this.

  ```
    const emailAddress = = "###"; // Please set the email for `to`.
    const subject = 'Hello World ・';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      emailAddress,
      `=?UTF-8?B?${Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.newBlob(subject).getBytes())}?=`,
      "sample text body"
    );
  ```

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: users.messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send)
- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)
- Related thread

  - [How to insert an emoji into an email sent with GmailApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50686254)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Man, thank you so so much. It worked flawlessly. I just want to ask one more thing. Is there any quota associated with how many emails we can send when Gmail API? I know with GmailApp/MailApp, we can send about 1000 emails per day.

Comment: @Ravgeet Dhillon Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, is this official document useful? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota

Comment: `=?UTF_B**?=` Is this a code? How did you find it?

Comment: @TheMaster In that time, I might have checked [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-seealso). In the current stage, I think that you can also use [this](https://www.sendblaster.com/utf8-email-subject-encoder/). In this case, `Hello World ⭐` is converted to `=?UTF-8?B?SGVsbG8gV29ybGQg8J+Yg+KtkA==?=`. When this encoded value is used as the subject at Gmail and sent, you can see the decoded value.

Comment: Thank you :D You should modify this to accept `replyTo` params as well - I would do this but I actually found your snippet via GitHub and then clicked to this SO thread, so best you do it (that way it can be updated in all places )

Comment: @The King Rowan Thank you for your comment. I'm glad my answer was useful. Thank you, too.

Comment: Update here on replyTo, I ended up asking ChatGPT to modify the function. Simple change and easier to share by mentioning that then pasting code or explaining lol.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into your html code:

.<img data-emoji="" class="an1" alt="" aria-label="" src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/e/notoemoji/15.0/1f60d/72.png" loading="lazy"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).