# Creating an Emoji-Compatible Gmail draft with Advanced Gmail Service in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, emoji

I'm trying to [create a Gmail draft](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/create) with the Gmail Advance Service. What I need is to have the `body` contain `data` in [bytes format](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages.attachments#MessagePartBody). I built the following funciton:

```js
const createDraftWithAdvancedService = () => {
  Gmail.Users.Drafts.create({
    message: {
      payload: {
        parts: [
          {
            body: {
              data: [
                42,
                123,
                123,
                80,
                114,
              ],
            }
          }
        ],
        headers: [
          {
            "value": "This is a test subject",
            "name": "Subject"
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }, 'user@domain.com');
}
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to gmail.users.drafts.create failed with error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "data" at 'draft.message.payload.parts[0].body': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.

The error looks strange as I'm following the index properly (or so I believe after checking a hundred times).

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

The reason I'm formatting my bytes string as an array is because that's what the Gmail API return when you *read* a draft. If you have a different **working** code, I'm all ears. And I can't use `raw`, I need to set the bytes string.

Here's an example of how a message object is retrieved and its format:

My draft message:

[image]

The script that retrives this draft message:

```js
const getMessage = () => {
  const id = 'r-8326849559354985208';
  const msg = Gmail.Users.Drafts.get('user@domain.com', id);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(msg, null, 2));
}
```

The output of the script:

```json
{
  "message": {
    "internalDate": "1633701716000",
    "snippet": "Draft body",
    "labelIds": [
      "DRAFT"
    ],
    "historyId": "954861",
    "sizeEstimate": 534,
    "payload": {
      "filename": "",
      "parts": [
        {
          "partId": "0",
          "headers": [
            {
              "value": "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"",
              "name": "Content-Type"
            }
          ],
          "filename": "",
          "body": {
            "data": [
              68,
              114,
              97,
              102,
              116,
              32,
              98,
              111,
              100,
              121,
              13,
              10
            ],
            "size": 12
          },
          "mimeType": "text/plain"
        },
        {
          "headers": [
            {
              "value": "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"",
              "name": "Content-Type"
            }
          ],
          "partId": "1",
          "body": {
            "size": 33,
            "data": [
              60,
              100,
              105,
              118,
              32,
              100,
              105,
              114,
              61,
              34,
              108,
              116,
              114,
              34,
              62,
              68,
              114,
              97,
              102,
              116,
              32,
              98,
              111,
              100,
              121,
              60,
              47,
              100,
              105,
              118,
              62,
              13,
              10
            ]
          },
          "mimeType": "text/html",
          "filename": ""
        }
      ],
      "body": {
        "size": 0
      },
      "headers": [
        {
          "value": "1.0",
          "name": "MIME-Version"
        },
        {
          "value": "Fri, 8 Oct 2021 16:01:56 +0200",
          "name": "Date"
        },
        {
          "value": "<CADVhnimBt3Jdod1wBgGUgB_75yrsoJMwM68mtYKmX6cN39=CNQ@mail.gmail.com>",
          "name": "Message-ID"
        },
        {
          "name": "Subject",
          "value": "Draft subject"
        },
        {
          "name": "From",
          "value": "\"KOSTYUK, Dmitry\" <user@domain.com>"
        },
        {
          "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=\"00000000000088918105cdd7d2e1\"",
          "name": "Content-Type"
        }
      ],
      "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
      "partId": ""
    },
    "id": "17c6035e45454be8",
    "threadId": "17c6035c50e83b2f"
  },
  "id": "r-8326849559354985208"
}
```

Comment: > A base64-encoded string.

Comment: It should be a `string`. I don't think you should be using `payload`, but just `message:{raw:"b64string"}`

Comment: @Kos what makes you think it should be a base64-encoded string?

Comment: @TheMaster please see my updated question. I'd be really grateful if you could post an answer with a working version of the code. And I can't use `raw`, I need the bytes string

Comment: See [python guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts#python). You need `raw`. Creating a MIMEText without libraries is a bit difficult, but doable. I think @Tanaike has some answers with creating MIMEText compliant with RFC2822

Comment: I can't use `raw`. The only reason I'm going through the advanced service, is that I need to make my script emoji-compatible. GmailApp only supports 1-character emojis, but not 2-character ones. `raw` has the same problem.

Comment: Here you [go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50883782/)

Comment: @TheMaster thank you, I was able to adapt the Advanced Gmail Service part in the cited answer to make things work for me. I will write up an answer soon as you suggested. StackOverflow seems to be the only place where this behavior is documented. I also  have to figure out attachments now, but that's a different issue

Comment: Although this approach still doesn't work for including emojis in the subject line

Comment: Update: found how to do both things thanks to this module's documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mimetext Answer coming up ;)

Comment: In order to include emoji in the subject and body, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66088350

Comment: @Tanaike, yes, thank you :) I had already figured out the trick

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks for your contribution, answer posted

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks, just letting you know I posted an answer and you might be interested

Comment: I think that it is a nice answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research and learning the RFC2822 MIMEText syntax, I have the definite answer to the problem. I will answer in three parts:

1. What Didn't Work
2. Solution One: the Hard Way
3. Solution Two: the New Easy Way

### What Didn't Work

What doesn't work is using the actual `Message` object like I did in my question. Don't ask me why, it's not documented anywhere, it just doesn't work. Even if you copy all or existing parts of the JSON object from another message via `Gmail.Users.Drafts.get()`, GAS will still throw an error.

So what goes in is **not** what gets returned, even though the documentation says otherwise.

Hence the only solution is to use the `raw` property of the message object, which must be a base-64-encoded string in the RFC2822 format.

### Solution One: the Hard Way

Combining the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686254/how-to-insert-an-emoji-into-an-email-sent-with-gmailapp/50883782#50883782) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66077675/how-to-use-emoji-in-email-subject-using-google-apps-script/66088350#66088350) allowed to create a basic function that generates a draft message with emojis:

```js
function convert(toEmail, fromEmail, subject, body) {
  body = Utilities.base64Encode(body, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  subject = Utilities.base64Encode(subject, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  const boundary = "boundaryboundary";
  const mailData = [
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "To: " + toEmail,
    "From: " + fromEmail,
    "Subject: =?utf-8?B?" + subject + "?=",
    "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=" + boundary,
    "",
    "--" + boundary,
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
    "",
    body,
    "",
    "--" + boundary,
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
    "",
    body,
    "",
    "--" + boundary,
  ].join("\r\n");
  return mailData;
}

function makeApiDraft() {
  const subject = "Hello MimeText World";
  const body = 'This is a plain text message';
  const me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  const raw = convert('test@test.com', me, subject, body);
  const b64 = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(raw);
  console.log(raw)
  Gmail.Users.Drafts.create({ message: { raw: raw } }, me);
}
```

Nothing wrong with this solution, it works.  However, if you want to go beyond this example, like adding multiple recipients, having  different plain text and html bodies, managing attachments, etc., you will have to code it all by hand and that requires understanding the RFC2822 MIMEText format.

Hence enter the new easier solution.

### Solution Two: the New Easy Way

I stumbled upon [this library](https://github.com/muratgozel/MIMEText) that generates MIMEText emails written in Node.js. So I thought perfect. I forked the repo and adapted a few things to make it GAS-compatible, specifically:

1. Base 64 encoding is done with `Utilities.base64Encode()` and `Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe()`
2. Attaching files is done by simply passing a GAS `DriveApp.File` object
3. I made sure proper MIMEText headers and base 64 encoding were present where they were needed.

And while my pull request is pending, I transpiled the whole thing with Webpack (as the library does have a dependency) and published it as a GAS library under this ID:

```
1HzFRRghlhuCDl0FUnuE9uKAK39GfeuUJAE3oOsjv74Qjq1UW8YEboEit
```

Here's [an example project](https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/1sLGOSKq_KINZVt5DU9PVlS33Iz_tWZCL3-xzTv4Um5jzsLxnnv3czUg-/edit) that you can use to test it out, but the code is basically as follows:

```js
const testMimeText = () => {
  const { message } = MimeText;
  message.setSender({
    name: 'Dmitry Kostyuk',
    addr: 'dmitry.kostyuk@gmail.com',
  });
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById('1pdMwlGL1WZTbi-Q2-Fc7nBm-9NKphkKg');
  const me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  message.setRecipient('dmitry.kostyuk@gmail.com');
  message.setSubject('Hello MimeText World!');
  message.setMessage('This is a plain text message ' + getAllEmojis(), 'text/plain');
  message.setMessage('<p>This is an html message</p><p>' + getAllEmojis() + '</p>\r\n\r\n', 'text/html');
  message.setAttachments([file]);

  const raw = message.asEncoded();
  Gmail.Users.Drafts.create({ message: { raw: raw } }, me);
}

const getDriveAuth = () => DriveApp.getRootFolder();
```

I guess I went down a rabbit hole I never expected to, but I'm pretty happy with how it turned out :)