# Limiting OAuth scope for Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

I am trying to limit my OAuth scopes in my script that sends an email after a form has been submitted. I want to limit it so that it has the least permission needed. If I click run, it tries to authorize the correct permissions. If I set up the on form submit trigger, it wants to authorize read, change, delete on all spreadsheets and change on all forms.

If I give the script full access to sheets and forms, it runs as intended. I just want to reduce some of the permissions. The screenshot shows that it is asking for more permission than what is specified in the appsscript.json file.

This script is attached to the responses sheet generated from my form.

From my `appsscript.json`:

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ]
```

The code:

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var values = e.namedValues;

  var htmlBody = 'Hey ' + values['Name of Recipient'] + "!<br>";
  htmlBody += values['Name of Sender'] + " thinks you deserve a shoutout! Thank you for being so awesome!";
  htmlBody += '<br> <em>' + values['Shoutout'] + " - " + values['Name of Sender'] + "</em>";
  htmlBody += '<br><br>';

  GmailApp.sendEmail(values['Recipient Email'],'SHOUT OUT!!!!!!','',
  {from:'email@domain.com',
  htmlBody:htmlBody});
}
```

Google Form/Sheet Questions/Columns

- Timestamp
- Name of Sender
- Name of Recipient
- Name of Recipient's Boss
- Shoutout
- Recipient Email
- Recipient's Boss Email

OAuth Permissions Screenshot:

[image: OAuth Permissions Screenshot]

Project Details OAuth Scopes:

- View your email messages and settings https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
- Send email on your behalf https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send
- See, edit, create, and delete only the specific Google Drive files you use with this app  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
- View and manage forms that this application has been installed in https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly
- View and manage spreadsheets that this application has been installed in  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I do not want the script to "See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheets" or "View and manage your forms in Google Drive". I want the script to only be able to access this particular sheet and its responses.

Comment: The screenshot url. Could you paste it here after removing sensitive information like clientid, client secret?

Comment: @RayFranosa The  information is still visible in the edit history. If you want complete erasure, "flag" your question and the answer containing sensitive information for "moderator intervention" and explain. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327142/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheets` is a required scope if you added an **Installable Trigger** that has event source of **From Spreadsheet** and `View and manage your forms in Google Drive` is also added if the event type is **On form submit**. This is to give script the access to the changes that may happen in the spreadsheet caused by submitting response. As a result, it will return the user an Event Object containing information about the context that caused the trigger to fire.

The script will also work if you manually press **Run** but there is no  Event Object that will be passed to the function parameter.

You can try using **Time-driven** as event source and it will show the same scope as you declared in `appsscript.json` since the trigger doesn't need to access the spreadsheet to execute the trigger.

**Example:**

**Time Driven:**

[image]

**From spreadsheet and On Open:**

[image]

**From spreadsheet and On form submit:**

[image]

### References:

- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: This is it. I did not notice the difference in the required permissions for those triggers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From your question, you want to restrict the scopes for your showing script of `The code:` as follows.

  ```
    /**
     * @OnlyCurrentDoc
     */

    function onFormSubmit(e) {
      var values = e.namedValues;

      var htmlBody = 'Hey ' + values['Name of Recipient'] + "!<br>";
      htmlBody += values['Name of Sender'] + " thinks you deserve a shoutout! Thank you for being so awesome!";
      htmlBody += '<br> <em>' + values['Shoutout'] + " - " + values['Name of Sender'] + "</em>";
      htmlBody += '<br><br>';

      GmailApp.sendEmail(values['Recipient Email'],'SHOUT OUT!!!!!!','',
      {from:'email@domain.com',
      htmlBody:htmlBody});
    }
  ```

It seems that when `GmailApp.sendEmail` of Gmail Service is used, the scope is constant as `https://mail.google.com/`. It seems that this is the current specification. So when you want to restrict the scopes, I think that you can achieve it using Gmail API. When your script is converted using Gmail API, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

// This is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66088350
function convert_(toEmail, fromEmail, subject, textBody, htmlBody) {
  const boundary = "boundaryboundary";
  const mailData = [
    `MIME-Version: 1.0`,
    `To: ${toEmail}`,
    `From: ${fromEmail}`,
    `Subject: =?UTF-8?B?${Utilities.base64Encode(subject, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)}?=`,
    `Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=${boundary}`,
    ``,
    `--${boundary}`,
    `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`,
    ``,
    textBody,
    ``,
    `--${boundary}`,
    `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`,
    `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`,
    ``,
    Utilities.base64Encode(htmlBody, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8),
    ``,
    `--${boundary}--`,
  ].join("\r\n");
  return Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(mailData);
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var htmlBody = 'Hey ' + values['Name of Recipient'] + "!<br>";
  htmlBody += values['Name of Sender'] + " thinks you deserve a shoutout! Thank you for being so awesome!";
  htmlBody += '<br> <em>' + values['Shoutout'] + " - " + values['Name of Sender'] + "</em>";
  htmlBody += '<br><br>';

  var raw = convert_(values['Recipient Email'], 'email@domain.com', 'SHOUT OUT!!!!!!', "", htmlBody);
  Gmail.Users.Messages.send({raw: raw}, "me");
}
```

- In this script, only tne scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send` can be used.
- **In this sample script, it supposes that `e` is the correct value you want to use. Please be careful about this.**

#### Note:

- About other scopes of `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"`, when I saw your script, those scopes are not required to be used. But, when Google Form is used, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly` might be required to be used. Please be careful this.
- **For example, when you want to use other methods, please add the scopes for them. My answer is for your showing script in your question. Please be careful about this.**

#### Reference:

- [Method: users.messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send)

Comment: @RayFranosa Now I understood your edit. I apologize that I couldn't notice it.