# How to send an e-mail to display "\n " newline followed by half width space?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, whitespace

[Problems facing]
If I put a "blank" immediately after entering "\n (line feed)" in the body, the "blank" becomes two.
[Script]

```
function sendEmail() {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "test＠example.com",
    subject: "Test",
    body: "───────────────\n Hello, world!", //<-1 blank
  });
}
```

[Result]
───────────────
  Hello, world! <-2 blanks at the beginning


[What I tried]

```
function sendEmail() {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "test＠example.com",
    subject: "Test",
    body: "───────────────\n&nbsp;Hello, world!",
  });
}
```

[Result]
───────────────
&nbsp;Hello, world! <-displayed as is

[want to achieve]
I'm asking for one blank display.

Comment: What is a “half-width space”? A “blank” or “&nbsp” are the same.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
“Half-width space” means “blank”.

Comment: Japanese has 2-byte spaces and 1-byte spaces. We call a 2-byte space a "full-width space" and a 1-byte space a "half-width space."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [Unicode escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#escape_sequences) with the required [whitespace character in unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)(For eg, `200A`(hair space) or `2009`(thin space)):

```
body: "───────────────\n\u{00A0}Hello, world!"
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66088350/

Comment: thank you for your reply.
Valid answer, very helpful. I was able to accomplish this successfully.

Comment: Unfortunately, teratail.com has flagged your answer as "a post that does not answer the question."
https://teratail.com/questions/eh3p5k6rp935zd

Comment: @YoPoppinKa I don't understand what that means for me... If you want the reason that it doesn't work with your original script, it is because your editor or os or something else doesn't allow you to directly input "half width space". The code you showed contains only a space (`\u{0020}`) and not a  half width space(`\u{00A0}`) here: `body: "───────────────\n Hel`: The space between \n and `Hel` is U+0020 only.