# GAS insert emoji into a table

Tags: google-apps-script

I am sending an email that contains a table.

The output is a table in the email where the first column should be the emoji follow by the name and date.

When I tried to put the emoji into the column of my array, the output in the column 1 of the table is a black ? triangle.

My code snippet is below -

```
for (let indx =0; indx<empDates.length; ++indx){
  if (empDates[indx][startMonthIndx]!="") {
    var tempDate = new Date(empDates[indx][startMonthIndx+1]);
    if (tempDate.getMonth() >= monDate.getMonth() && tempDate.getDate() >= monDate.getDate() && tempDate.getMonth() <= sunDate.getMonth() && tempDate.getDate()<= sunDate.getDate()) {
      var emojiType = empDates[indx][startMonthIndx];

      if (emojiType.indexOf("(B)")==0) {
        var emojiIcon = '';
      } else {
        var emojiIcon = '';
      }

      thisWeekReminder.push(emojiIcon, [empDates[indx][startMonthIndx], empDates[indx][startMonthIndx+1]]);
    }

    if (startMonth != endMonth) {
      tempDate = new Date(empDates[indx][startMonthIndx+3]);
      if (empDates[indx][startMonthIndx+2]!="") {
        if (tempDate.getMonth() >= monDate.getMonth() && tempDate.getDate() >= monDate.getDate() && tempDate.getMonth() <= sunDate.getMonth() && tempDate.getDate()<= sunDate.getDate()) {
          var emojiType = empDates[indx][startMonthIndx];

          if (emojiType.indexOf("(B)")==0) {
            var emojiIcon = '';
          } else {
            var emojiIcon = '';
          }
  
          thisWeekReminder.push(emojiIcon, [empDates[indx][startMonthIndx+2], empDates[indx][startMonthIndx+3]]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailTable');

htmlTemplate.name = name;
htmlTemplate.specialDate = specialDate;
htmlTemplate.tablerangeValue = thisWeekReminder;

const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

var toEmail = emailAddr[0][0];
var ccEmail = "";

for (let i=1; i<emailAddr.length; ++i) {
  if (emailAddr[i][0] != "") {
    if (i=1) {
      ccEmail = emailAddr[i][0];
    } else {
      ccEmail = ccEmail + "," + emailAddr[i][0];
    }
  }
}

MailApp.sendEmail({
to: toEmail,
cc: ccEmail,
subject: "REMINDER: This week's Birthdays and Anniversaries",
htmlBody:htmlForEmail
  });
```

}
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an emoji into an email sent with GmailApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686254/how-to-insert-an-emoji-into-an-email-sent-with-gmailapp)